# Unable to unlock the Nexus 4 device

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am unable to unlock the Nexus 4 device. When I type

```
sudo fastboot oem unlock
```

and hit Enter, it says:

```
sudo: fastboot: command not found
```

Could you please help in fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Fist you need to install the andriod sdk tools. Even After installation if you are facing these error

then

You need create symbolic link.

Say your have installed the the andro-sdk in in home folder. **Determine correct path for your installation**

so, execute

`sudo ln -s ~/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/local/sbin/adb`

`sudo ln -s ~/android-sdk/platform-tools/fastboot /usr/local/sbin/adb`

to start adb deamon use

`sudo adb start-server`